# Monotonically increasing path in a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, random-graphs

Given a complete graph with n vertices such that all edge weights are distinct. Prove that we can find a monotonically increasing path of length n-1.

I tried finding such a path by sorting the edges in increasing weight and then greedily selecting such that they make up a path. eg: Lets consider a graph where $w_{a,b}=1, w_{a,c}=2, w_{a,d}=3, w_{b,c}=4, w_{b,d}=5, w_{c,d}=6$. I first select a->b. Then we find the next edge which starts from b and has the least weight. We get b->c. And so on. The path I get is : a->b->c->d. But I'm not able to prove that this will always work. Any suggestions?

I think the problem is similar to [Counting certain paths in a complete graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136005/counting-certain-paths-in-a-complete-graph).

Comment: How does your greedy algorithm work if $w_{a,b}=1,w_{a,c}=3,w_{a,d}=4,w_{b,c}=5,w_{b,d}=6,w_{c,d}=2$?

Comment: @bof my greedy strategy fails. Thanks for the counter-example. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Not offhand, no.

Comment: Are "paths" for you allowed to repeat vertices? Also, since you tagged this "random-graphs", does that mean you should be thinking more in terms of probabilistic methods?

Comment: @Casteels repeating and not-repeating vertices can be two variants to think upon.

Comment: Regarding random-graphs, I was trying to think in the following direction: if we build a complete graph with random edge weights in (0,1), what is the probability that a path of length $n-1$ is monotonic?

Comment: The reason I was asking is that I found this paper available online: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/73_01_increasing_paths.pdf [In case the link ever goes dead, this is Graham and Kleitman, "Increasing Paths in Edge Ordered Graphs," Periodica Mathematica Hungarica Vol 3 (1973)]. So in the case that repeated vertices are allowed, I believe their Theorem 1 easily implies what you want, but in the case that no repeated vertices are allowed (what they call simple paths), it appears it was a hard open problem, at least 40 years ago. But it's not unlikely some probabilists have since proved it.

Comment: Oh actually, maybe I didn't read it carefully enough. It appears that they do give a construction of an assignment of $1,...,{n\choose 2}$ to the edges of some complete graph such that there is no increasing path of length more than $\frac{3}{4}n$.

Answer (score 3):

The following argument is from [a column by Peter Winkler](https://doi.org/10.1145/1378727.1389570), attributed to Ehud Friedgut; it may be equivalent to Graham and Kleitman's argument, but is easier to read. It works in the general case of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, where the edges are labeled with distinct weights.

Put a person on each vertex in the graph, and announce the edges in increasing order of their weights (from the lowest-weight to the highest-weight edge). Every time an edge is announced, have the two people standing on its endpoints switch places.

When this is done, each of the $n$ people has walked an increasing walk. (This walk might repeat vertices, so it's not an increasing simple path; that problem is much harder.) Also, the total number of steps taken is $2m$, because every time an edge is announced, two people each take a step. Therefore someone must have taken at least $2m/n$ steps: in the case $G = K_n$, this gives $n-1$.

Here are some comments about variants of this problem.

**What about *greedy* increasing walks?** Well, in the algorithm above, each person walks a greedy increasing walk. So although we can't guarantee that there's a long greedy walk from any vertex, there is at least one starting vertex from which the greedy increasing walk is long.

**What about simple paths rather than walks, if we forbid repeating vertices?** This is a much harder problem, and we're not sure if we can always get a path whose length is linear in $n$, but [a recent paper by Bucić et al.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-020-2035-7) has found a way to get $n^{1-o(1)}$. A [construction by Calderbank et al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(84)90031-1) shows that we can't do better than $(\frac12+o(1))n$; this result is the oldest of the ones cited in this answer, dating back to 1984, but no better construction has been found as far as I know.

The argument that gives $n-1$ for increasing walks can be modified to give $\sqrt{n-1}$ for increasing paths. When an edge is announced, allow either person to say "no, I've been to the other vertex already", in which case both people stay put. At the end, every walk is a path. If the longest path is $\ell$ edges, then each person rejects at most $\binom \ell 2$ edges, leaving at least $\binom n2 - n \binom \ell2$ un-rejected edges. Therefore at least one person takes at least $n-1 - \ell(\ell-1)$ steps, and $\ell \ge n-1 - \ell(\ell-1)$ gives us $\ell \ge \sqrt{n-1}$.

**What happens in random graphs?** If we take $K_n$ and give each edge a random weight (for example, from $[0,1]$, though the distribution doesn't matter), then [Martinsson proved](https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20803) that with probability tending to $1$, there is an increasing *path* of length $n-1$.

This was an improvement on a result by me and my advisor, where [we proved](https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20592) a lower bound of $\frac1e$ on the limiting probability. I mention this because we also proved that in a random edge-labeling, a *greedy* algorithm finds a path of length $(\frac1e+o(1))n$ with probability tending to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I should make my comments an answer.

I found the following in an [old paper of Graham and Kleitman](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/73_01_increasing_paths.pdf) ("Increasing Paths in Edge Ordered Graphs," Periodica Mathematica Hungarica Vol 3 (1973)).

If by "path" you allow repeated vertices (what is often called a trail these days), then their Theorem 1 easily implies what you want (just relabel your edge weights by putting 1 to your least edge weight, 2 as your second least edge weight etc).

If by "path" you mean no repeated vertices (what they call "simple path"), then the answer to your question is no, and here is a counterexample derived from their Section IV. Consider $K_{4}$ with vertices $a,b,c,d$, and edge weights: $w_{a,b}=1$, $w_{b,c}=6$,$w_{c,d}=2$, $w_{d,a}=5$, $w_{b,d}=4$, $w_{a,c}=3$.

<strike>**PS** I just realized bof's example is also a counterexample.</strike>

Comment: In bof's example, cadb is an increasing path.