# If edges are labeled with consecutive integers, there exists a strictly increasing sequence in a path of length atleast n-1 in a complete graph.

Tags: graph-theory

> A path visits distinct edges, but may visit the same vertex multiple
> times. Label the edges of a complete graph $K_n$ such that each edge
> is a distinct integer less from $1$ to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Show that there is a
> strictly increasing sequence of labels in a walk of length at least
> $n-1$.

I have read [Monotonically increasing path in a complete graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556877/monotonically-increasing-path-in-a-complete-graph) but couldn't understand the Theorem 1 mentioned in the answer.

I have a hint that I would like to use:

*Assign a weight $w$ to each vertex $x$ whose value is the length of the longest increasing path such that $x$ is the last vertex of that trail. Now, show that $\sum_w w(x) \ge n(n-1)$. Using this proves the previous statement.*

<s>I realize that the weight of each vertex is the same and therefore it does add up to $n(n-1)$. But I am not sure how to prove it. So as each vertex has $n-1$ weight, a path of length $n-1$ is the minimum length path with strictly increasing labels.</s> edit: $\sum_w w(x) \ge n(n-1)$,because of $K_4$ with $w(a,b)=1$, $w(b,c)=2$, $w(c,a)=3$, $w(c,d)=4$, $w(d,b)=5$, $w(d,a)=6$ gives $14>12$

Proposed solution adapted from the linked paper by Graham, Kleitman:
Starting from a $K_3$(it has a sum of weights $= 6$, which is satisfactory), adding a new vertex and a new edge to it from the vertex with the largest weight adds at least $2$ to the sum of weights, then we add $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such edges in total, therefore the total weight is at least $n(n-1)$. Then over $n$ vertices, the weight is at least $n-1$ for one vertex. Said vertex has a path of length $n-1$ that is monotonically increasing in terms of edge ordering.

Comment: I've added an answer to this question, but I've decided to post it as an answer to the older question, rather than this one.