From Peter Winkler's Puzzle Book
Can anybody kindly explain the proof of the following theorem from Peter Winkler's book " Mathematical Puzzles":
Theorem. Let G be an arbitrary graph with an arbitrary ordering of its edges.
Then there is an increasing walk in G of length at least the average degree of G.
Thanks.

Does the answer here explain the proof for you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556877/monotonically-increasing-path-in-a-complete-graph/4871797#4871797

Many of us may not have that book. Can you post the proof and explain the part or parts that you don't understand?
